# ActionBar Lag in hiding title

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using the `ActionBarSherlock` for my application and this is the code I use to hide the `Title` of `ActionBar` :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_fragment);
}
```

The problem with this is that when the application starts there is a short amount of time when  the `Logo` and `Title` are shown simultaneously. This looks really ugly, How can I get rid of that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is my solution, we need to define a new style and declare it in the Manifest

```
<style name="VibhinnaTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.ForceOverflow">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/VibhinnaTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/VibhinnaTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="VibhinnaTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
</style>
```

This link was helpful : [LINK](https://groups.google.com/group/actionbarsherlock/browse_thread/thread/b228ab55d670fadb)

Comment: This is the correct solution. The "lag" is the delay between creating the decor view and your `onCreate` executing.

Comment: Jake, is it possible to short this lag?

Comment: I'll answer: no. Here is a great post about that subject: android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=873
BTW thanks for the answer, I wasn't finding too much in the official docs.

Comment: What flags do you use to remove both the icon and title?

Comment: @user1923613 Follow this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14998204/1054366 In short, you set the title to "transparent". And thus there is no lag.

Comment: Take a look at the answer above, @Binoy Babu. It removed the delay on my case.