# How to hide the actionbar before the Activity is loaded?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My goal is to show a splash screen on my applications startup. Right now what it will do is briefly show the actionbar with an otherwise blank page, then jump to the splash screen. I'm trying to figure out how to not show the beginning screen and just start with the splash screen. 
I'm trying to use these links for information on how to solve this.

[ActionBar Lag in hiding title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525734/actionbar-lag-in-hiding-title)
In this one I'm assuming I can use the same type of method for hiding the actionbar by changing the theme, but I don't know what I would actually use as my style to do so.

[How to hide action bar before activity is created, and then show it again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500283/how-to-hide-action-bar-before-activity-is-created-and-then-show-it-again)
and here it talks about adding a line to the manifest that would do it. Where in the manifest? Anywhere I put it did not do anything.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

try this in manifest file

```
<activity
        android:name="yourActivityName"
        android:label="your label"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >

    </activity>
```

Comment: How do I get the actionbar back after the splash screen?

Comment: on which phone you are testing?

Comment: HTC One XL. That shouldn't matter though. I tried using this.getApplication().setTheme(16973934); to change the theme back but  it doesn't do anything

Comment: from which phone I mean to say that which OS...but the reason off crash should not be this..If you remove this line app runs smoothly?

Comment: Sorry fixed the crash, I was calling a nullPointer when calling getActionBar. It runs fine but I need my actionBar IN the app after the splash screen. Can't figure out how to get it back.

Comment: I think you put this line in Application tag. Just place in `Activity` tag of your splash activity. I also edit my answer..and don't forget to accept the answer if it helps you.

Comment: Wouldn't android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 5):

Check this link [Android: hide action bar while view load](https://t.co/AEfC6wsdOY)

Code snippets from the link, incase the link breaks down, courtesy @kleopatra:

> Setting the properties `windowNoTitle` to true on your theme  will
>   hide the ActionBar. use two different themes both extending `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"`  in order to prevent NPE when using getSupportActionBar

set the styles as

> ```
> <style name="AppThemeNoBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
>         <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
> </style>
> <style name="AppThemeBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
>         <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
> </style>
> ```
>
> Due to some odd behaviour on versions < 11,  you need to add
>
> if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11){
>       getSupportActionBar().hide();  }
>
> inside activities that do not need the actionbar

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the "android:label" entries in Manifest file, from application and the first activity which is loaded. In your case, the Splash activity.
Sample...

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/starticon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo">

    <activity
        android:name=".ActivitySplash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code in your Activity in the onCreate function.

```
val actionBar = supportActionBar?.apply{hide()}
```