# status bar icon should be different from launcher icon

Tags: android

I am using android 4.2 SDK, by default the status bar shows the launch icon but I want to use a different icon for the app's Launch icon and status bar icon

what I am doing

```
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:name=".CommonMethod"
   android:logo="@drawable/toolbar_logo"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
        android:name=".TimerClockActivity"
      android:icon="@drawable/toolbar_logo"
          android:label="@string/ActivityToolBar"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >

         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter> 

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PrefsActivity"

       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Activity's `onCreate` method called the method `getActionBar.setIcion()` method and pass the Id of the icon. Check out this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setIcon%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) for further help

Comment: Question is how to change status bar icon, not action bar icon. So when you are switching between apps, what icon is shown there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the icon of the action bar by using styles. Go have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978809/can-i-set-the-home-icon-of-my-actionbar-using-styles-xml)
link. It should answer your question.