# Remove icon from searchView widget (not in actionBar)

Tags: java, android, user-interface, customization, searchview

I want to customize a searchView widget in my App. Point is to remove magnifier glass icon from it (not to make it transparent, just remove).
To make it easier to understand here are some screenshots:

How it looks now:

[image: 1]

And how it supposed to look:

[image]

I can use editText instead, but it doesn't have suggestions, which is important for me.

Comment: possible duplicate - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806877/remove-icon-title-for-actionbar-with-expanded-searchview]

Comment: "I can use editText instead, but it doesn't have suggestions, which is important for me" -- why not use `AutoCompleteTextView`, then?

Comment: Dhwanik Gandhi - Read question title. NOT IN ACTIONBAR

Autocomplete is not acceptable because I need list with suggestions, not autocomplete.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that the SearchView is extending LinearLayout. I guess the orientation is horizontal.

You could get the instance of SearchView and then remove the first child. I have not tried this but I think it will work.

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.search);
// You have to play around with this but I think 0 is the right value
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) searchView.getChildAt(0);
linearLayout.removeViewAt(1);
```

Comment: code added but you need to replace it with your own

Comment: In that way all elements of searchView is disappearing.

Comment: Unfortunately updatet code does nothing. If I change view ID - nullPointer Excepton is thrown.