# How to hide the logo on Sherlock action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I want to remove the icon on action bar and i want to display only title. I did it by using

```
ActionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
```

and

```
ActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

But the action bar is showing below the tab.so please help me how to solve the issue. 
thanks in advance.`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove icon/logo from action bar on android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606294/remove-icon-logo-from-action-bar-on-android)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't actually tried, but I believe you can specifying the display options in such a way as to only display the title:

```
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

If you'd like to do it purely through XML, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14998204/154306) recommends:

```
<item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
<item name="displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
<item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Comment: hi thanks for your response,actually i tried but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/YourActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/YourActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="YourActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showTitle</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">showTitle</item>
</style>
```

And in your Activity:

```
ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

It worked for me! Hope this help.