# how to hide android logo from actionbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm using navigation drawer in my application. I want to get rid of the android's robot icon from the action  bar. I'm using the following lines but the logo is not disappearing.

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Can anyone suggest me what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this to your activity

> getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));

Answer (score 1):

```
getActionBar().setLogo(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
```

Works as well.

Answer (score 0):

to hide the logo add below line also

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

See this link also [Android remove app icon action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21602713/android-remove-app-icon-action-bar)

Comment: I had tried this line, by adding this line the drawer icon also disappears.

Answer (score 0):

This will done the magic:

1.) Add the following lines into your styles.xml:

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    ...
```

2.) And don't forget to add your style into your AndroidManifest.xml (if you haven't already done it):

```
    <application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        ...
```

Hope this helps!