# Actionbar menu text color showing as transparent

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to hide the app icon from the action bar.For this i wrote following lines in the style to hide app icon:

```
<item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

its work for me but it also hide the menu text its showing menu as transparent. but menu text color is white.

Comment: Did you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606294/remove-icon-logo-from-action-bar-on-android

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your action bar styles:

```
<item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
<item name="displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
<item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide complete **action bar** use this code in MainActivity.java before calling this line `SetContentview`

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);   // This code will hide Action Bar form your UI
setContentView(R.layout.mailActivity);
```

---

Updated : use this to hide application icon

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, com.apps.MainActivity.class); // activity which is first time open in manifiest file which is declare as <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: i dont want to hide the action bar.

Comment: So you need to hide **AppIcon** only ? is it ? check my answer now I updated

Comment: yes working but same problem. it also hide the text of menu means it is transparent.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="AppTheme"
    parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:logo">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

This will work for you