# how to move actionbar home icon to Right side?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I,m using appcompat actionbar, I have moved navigation drawer to right side but the home icon still in the left side , how can I move it to Right side?!

Update:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't necessarily think there is a way to move the Icon to the right because the App Bar's default behavior. There is however a workaround, if it's what you're looking for then:

**1.** First step would be removing the ActionBar Icon: [See this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606294/remove-icon-logo-from-action-bar-on-android)

**2.** Then add another ActionBar button and have the button's icon to whatever icon you would like i.e. the 'Maps' icon.

**3.** This way, you have the icon, it's still clickable but you don't really have to add a click event for it unless needed.

Hopefully this helped you or atleast got some inspiration on what else you could do.

Comment: thanks , I have see some apps do that my app language is RLT so I need to move the action bar icon to right side

Comment: if I add a icon did it get to right side before the menu button , i want to make the home button set in the corner before the menu button , is it possible?

Comment: Hey Delta, I'm finding it hard for me to understand what you mean. Is it possible to clarify a bit more?

Comment: as you said i have to remove the default home icon and add a new one , so is it possible to add a button right side of the menu button (as you can see in the image ) ?

Comment: Like I've mentioned before, it's not possible to get the icon to appear all the way at the right side of the app (to my knowledge). The standard behavior only allows either to have it on the Left or hide it. Your alternative would be to make a button, just like how you've done with the `Search` and `GPS`.

Comment: I'm really not sure where to go from here. Maybe you could do a bit more research. Also can you please list some of those apps which you've seen. I want to take a look.

Comment: there is some apps that not in play market but you can download them , like cafebazaar you can download it from there website http://cafebazaar.ir/

Comment: Take a look at this post. It might help. Basically that user has added a NavigationDrawer to open from the Right Side. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156340/android-is-navigation-drawer-from-right-hand-side-possible I'm just not sure if you could do the same with a Action Bar