# Remove Search View icon from hint text

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, searchview, android-actionbar-compat

I am using appcompat library with a toolbar and I have implemented a search view in my app. But i want to remove the search view icon when its expanded. 
 
here is my menu xml file:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"/>
```

and this is how I inflate the menu:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search_hint));
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

this is what i want to remove:

[image]

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606294/remove-icon-logo-from-action-bar-on-android

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633952/how-to-delete-or-change-the-searchview-icon-inside-the-searchview-actionbar/33229228#33229228) out

Comment: Have you considered that what you want the **is** a `EditText`? I had SO MANY problems trying to make simple things in the `SearchView` that i concluded that it wasn't designed for customization.. a simple edit text with some style solved my problem with the icon

Comment: Follow this question answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63988419/6160172

Answer (score 23):

This helped me to remove Search icon

```
searchView.setIconified(false);
```

If you want searchView always expanded use just this:

```
searchView.onActionViewExpanded();
```

Comment: Perfect, after trying every solution, this one works!

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

In your app theme, add the following line:

```
<item name="searchViewStyle">@style/MySearchViewStyle</item>
```

Add define the style at below:

```
<style name="MySearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I prefer this solution over using private id's or reflection.  Just make sure you are using the support version of the SearchView (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView)

Comment: Does anyone know where to find the official documentation for the `searchViewStyle`?

Answer (score 6):

```
try {
    Field mDrawable = SearchView.class.getDeclaredField("mSearchHintIcon");
    mDrawable.setAccessible(true);
    Drawable drawable = (Drawable) mDrawable.get(searchView);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

setBounds does the magic

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is [Here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633952/how-to-delete-or-change-the-searchview-icon-inside-the-searchview-actionbar/47971535#47971535) In case of `AppCompat`

```
app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
app:searchIcon="@null"
```

OR in other case

```
android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
android:searchIcon="@null"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/xx_layout"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

and in xx_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:searchHintIcon="@null"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="true" />
```

Answer (score 2):

In your onCreateOptionsMenu

```
int searchPlateId = searchView.getContext().getResources()
            .getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
    EditText searchPlate = (EditText) searchView
            .findViewById(searchPlateId);
    searchPlate.setHint("");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the android source code for the layout of SearchView , you will see that the search icon has a id search_mag_icon. So in onCreateOptionsMenu,

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search,menu);
    MenuItem searchViewItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)searchViewItem.getActionView();        
    searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_mag_icon).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Just find the view by id and set its visibility to gone.

Answer (score 1):

For `androidx` and new version of `SearchView`:
If you add `SearchView` from code, it's effective for that.
Add new style in `styles.xm`

```
<style name="SearchViewMy" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView">
    <item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item>
</style>
```

and applied that `style` in your app `theme`:

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/SearchViewMy</item>
</style>
```

Or if you add `SearchView` from xml, then add this line in your layout:

```
app:searchHintIcon="@null"
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into [SumeetP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3782068/sumeetp)'s answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445760/how-to-change-the-default-icon-on-the-searchview-to-be-use-in-the-action-bar-on). Not sure if that works because I never used it.  He gets Search icon as an ImageView. So I guess you can just set image to `android.R.color.transparent` so that it won't be visible.

Comment: This hides the image on the actionbar not in the expanded searchview imo.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a customized search view just add this in your .xml layout

app:searchIcon="@null"
app:iconifiedByDefault="false"

Answer (score 0):

That's an old question, but this helped me a lot in my case: If you are trying to hide inside a menu, none of the questions posted here worked perfectly for me (Greetings for AK5T that almost solved my problem). What solved the problem was:
Instead of putting

```
app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
```

inside the item in menu, you can change for:

```
app:actionLayout="@layout/search_layout"
```

And, inside this layout, you can add this piece of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.SearchView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:searchHintIcon="@drawable/nothing_drawed"/>
```

And, finally, inside the drawable you just create it with nothing inside, example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</selector>
```

Only this method worked for me. When I tried to hide the searchHintIcon, setting to @null or anything else, it remained the same thing as if I had written no code.