# How to delete or change the searchview icon inside the SearchView actionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview, android-appcompat

[image: screenshot]

How to remove or change the search view icon inside the edittext?
I am using the Appcompat library.

I used the below code to modify and remove but it's not working:

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    View search_mag_icon = (View)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);
        search_mag_icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_stub);
        //search_mag_icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 24):

Finally found the solution. Try the following:

```
try {
    Field mDrawable = SearchView.class.getDeclaredField("mSearchHintIcon");
    mDrawable.setAccessible(true);
    Drawable drawable =  (Drawable)mDrawable.get(your search view here);
    drawable.setAlpha(0);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: After trying everything, it was the only solution working for me, thanks

Comment: adding this line **drawable.setBounds(0,0,0,0)** enables you to display hints with 0 left padding otherwise hints are displayed after icon which is still exists transparently.

Comment: It works but shows a warning **detects reflective access to fields `mSearchHintIcon` and methods which don't exist or aren't visible**

Answer (score 4):

Per the [AppCompat v21 blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html), you can provide a custom style for your `SearchView`, overriding things such as the search icon:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/MySearchViewStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="MySearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <!-- Search button icon -->
    <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/custom_search_icon</item>
</style>
```

Comment: He wants to remove this icon completely from the hint, and not replace it.

Comment: @Solace - replacing it with nothing == removing it

Comment: I tried `<item name="searchIcon"></item>`, which gives me `String types not allowed (at 'searchIcon' with value '').` I will really appreciate if you can guide me a bit on this? Did you try this yourself?

Comment: @Solace - you have to use `@null`, not just blank.

Comment: Didn't work for me =( Actually, none of those styles are being applied, posted a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31889725/why-dont-appcompat-v21-searchview-styles-dont-apply-in-my-app)

Comment: This is the only answer in this post that actually works as for today.... THANKS!!

Answer (score 2):

no a good idea use private method as `SearchView.class.getDeclaredField("mSearchHintIcon");`

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/xx_layout"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

and in xx_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:searchHintIcon="@null"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="true" />
```

Comment: On style, <item name="searchIcon">@null</item> and <item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item> do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You might use below lines of code:

```
int searchMagIcon = getResources().getIdentifier("search_mag_icon", "id", "android");
ImageView SearchHintIcon = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchMagIcon);
```

That will save the ImageView and then you can change it.

Answer (score 1):

I used the menu item with the property `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"`

On the activity I set:

```
searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

To remove the icon I did:

```
ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);
searchIcon.setImageDrawable(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove is the right drawable that you have mentioned in xml:

```
final Drawable remove = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_close_circle);
        etSearchProducts.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                if (etSearchProducts.getCompoundDrawables()[2] == null) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (event.getX() > etSearchProducts.getWidth() - etSearchProducts.getPaddingRight() - remove.getIntrinsicWidth()) {
                    etSearchProducts.setText("");
                    Utility.hideKeyboard(getActivity());
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is

1. In case you are using `AppCompat` use

   ```
       app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
       app:searchIcon="@null"
   ```
2. Else use `android` in place of `app` in above code as

   ```
   android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
   android:searchIcon="@null"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I was digging about that a lot and finally I found this solution and it works for me!
You can use this

If you use appcompat try this:

```
ImageView searchIconView = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_button);
searchIconView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourIcon);
```

If you use androidx try this:

```
ImageView searchIconView = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_button);
    searchIconView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourIcon);
```

It will change the default serchview icon.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Just to let you know that posting multiple identical answers to different questions will get automatically flagged for moderators to review. If you do come across questions to which a single answer would be able to answer both questions, you should consider flagging one of them as a duplicate of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the searchHintIcon property as null in your Searchview.

**app:searchHintIcon="@null"**