# How put the logo of toolbar at right?

Tags: android, drawable, toolbar

I did this to "inflate" the logo at the toolbar:

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.navigationIcon);
toolbar.getNavigationIcon().setTint(Color.BLUE);
toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
toolbar.getLogo().methodForFloatRightHere();
```

Does there exist some simple method that doesn't use "inflate" on a view?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28408768/set-app-icon-to-right-side-in-activity-tool-bar

Comment: NOT USING INFLATE, XD, i prefer not put more xml's in my project

Comment: the answers say how put a logo using a external view, at the least all that i found

Comment: Writing XML for making layout is always more elegant than writing code. New Toolbar is made for this reason that you can customise it in anyway you want. Just add an image in your Toolbar in your layout.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add custom views to a toolbar.

The key is the `android:layout_gravity="center"` on the logo `ImageView`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetEnd="@dimen/material_content_keyline"
    app:contentInsetStart="@dimen/material_content_keyline"
    app:navigationContentDescription="@string/abc_action_bar_up_description"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Keyline is 72dp on phones, 80dp on tablets. This ensures any views added to toolbar (besides navigation/collapse icon and menu items) are centered in a rectangle at least 72/80dp from left and right. Increase if you have more menu items and the logo leans to the left.

If you don't want to use XML:

```
mToolbar.addView(mLogo,
    new Toolbar.LayoutParams(Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER));
```

Comment: Or GravityCompat.END with no menu inflated if you want it aligned to right.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a menu with your application icon you want to put to the right as a menu item.

**res/menu/main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_item"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_application_icon"
    android:title="@string/aplication_icon"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

And then inflate it using

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your own view to have the logo on the right, unless you develop your app in RTL mode, which I do not think is what you really want. You can add a `RelativeLayout` to your `toolbar` element in XML and then have the `ImageView` gravity set to RIGHT.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the default toolbar you can use the toolbar with ta nested layout in which you can customize it according to your needs. For eg

`

```
<LinearLayout
    style="@style/Layout.Wrap"
    android:background="@color/sky_blue_dark"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/fivedp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_title_bar_menu"
            style="@style/Layout.Fill"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_side_menu"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_title_bar_previous"
            style="@style/Layout.Fill"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back_selected"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_title_bar_header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"

        android:textColor="@color/dark_blue_title_bar"
        android:textSize="@dimen/global_title_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_title_bar_popup"
            style="@style/Layout.Fill"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_benefits_popup_icon"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_title_bar_cart"
            style="@style/Layout.Fill"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_title_bar_cart"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_title_bar_edit_profile"
            style="@style/Layout.Fill"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_title_bar_edit_profile"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_title_bar_delete_all"
            style="@style/Layout.Fill"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_all"
            android:visibility="gone" />


    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`

In this way you can do anything inside the layout that is defined inside the ToolBar