# ActionBar menu Change the icon position

Tags: android

How can I change the icons of this menu?

[image]

and this my`xml` file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.niyazdel.jeeb.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/main_parent_id"
    android:title="menu"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/outline_more_vert_white_24">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_add"
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            android:title="@string/add"
            android:icon="@drawable/add"
            app:showAsAction="always" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_setting"
            android:orderInCategory="2"
            android:title="@string/action_setting"
            android:icon="@drawable/setting"
            app:showAsAction="always" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_about"
            android:orderInCategory="3"
            android:title="@string/action_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/about"
            app:showAsAction="always" />
    </menu>


</item>
```

Comment: usually through the attribute android:icon="@drawable/yourDrawable" in the menu.xml file of your options menu (under the specific item). If you could edit your post to include your code so far, we could provide a more specific answer

Comment: for future questions, you should add some code to see what your implementation is like! For this particular one, why dont you show a PopupWindow with a custom layout?

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I updated issue!

Comment: refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735407/how-put-the-logo-of-toolbar-at-right