# How can I customize the ActionBar

Tags: android

How can I set the ActionBar icons to the right and left and set its title to the center?
I can now put the title text to the center of it.
I want it similar to this screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Are you using material design?

Comment: i desinged a xml layout for display title bar center

Comment: follow the link-[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28408768/set-app-icon-to-right-side-in-activity-tool-bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28408768/set-app-icon-to-right-side-in-activity-tool-bar)

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own layout for the top bar and then, you will just have to put your custom elements in it.

As follow:

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);


ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.topbarclassic,null);
mActionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);
```

I'm using a custom layout I made, `R.layout.topbarclassic` as a top bar.

Just use a LinearLayout with some `gravity` to place your elements properly, and it's done! :)

Comment: thanks a lot, but I want to when clicked them . one of them open menu (sub items)

Comment: You can still, just set the listener of one of your buttons :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**res/menu/main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@+id/app_icon"
    android:icon="@drawable/your_app_icon"
    android:title="@string/app_icon"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

And overide the `onCreateOptionsMenu` in your **java code**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```