# How to remove the android actionbar icon in xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to remove the android actionbar icon in a Xamarin android project.

I have tried setting the icon as transparent and excluding the icon from the manifest. 
I have also tried changing the icon size to try and hide it and replacing it with a blank icon. Problem is that this also makes the icon in the launcher menu screen blank.

any suggestions would help

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606294/remove-icon-logo-from-action-bar-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the below code, it worked perfectly for me

```
ActionBar.SetIcon(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

in your MainActivity.cs, try this

```
    // hide app icon in Android action/nav bar
    ActionBar.SetIcon(my_app_name.Resource.Color.transparent);
```

Answer (score 1):

For a particular activity try this...

```
getActionBar().setIcon(
   new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got this solved by adding this code into my Android MainActivity class:

```
ActionBar.SetIcon(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);
```