# Remove Icon from ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is there a way to hide the app icon from the ActionBar; that is, have an ActionBar without an icon?

Here is my current code:

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#000000")));
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(" OrderIn");
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.actionbar_logo);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Try `actionBar.setIcon(null);`

Comment: Is the device you're programming for (or using) pre-Lollipop? On Lollipop the icon will not be shown on the actionbar by default.

Answer (score 2):

- similar ques : [Remove icon/logo from action bar on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606294/remove-icon-logo-from-action-bar-on-android)

If you've defined android:logo="..." in the  tag of your AndroidManifest.xml, then you need to use this stuff to hide the icon:

pre-v11 theme

```
<item name="logo">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

v11 and up theme

```
<item name="android:logo">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

The use of these two styles has properly hidden the action bar icon on a 2.3 and a 4.4 device for me (this app uses AppCompat).

Answer (score 0):

`setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(boolean)` is what you're after.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(boolean)