# How to hide NavigationIcon on toolbar

Tags: android

I have following design in my project - 
Activity (which have menuitems A, B, C, D)
if we click on menuItem A then a FragmentA opens.I'm adding this fragment on top of activity, So toolbar remains same. 
FragmentA onCreateView is -

```
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false)

            Activity.toolbar.setTitle("FragmentA");
            Activity.toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back_icon);

            Activity.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Activity.fragmentManager.popBackStack();
                    Activity.toolbar.setTitle("Activity");
                }
            }); 
}
```

So Basically in FragmentA I inflate Back Navigation Icon on toolbar. but i want to hide this icon when switch back to my Activity. I don't have any navigation icon or logo in Activity.

Comment: This might helps you  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606294/remove-icon-logo-from-action-bar-on-android

Comment: please share code of your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try setting the NavigationIcon to null while getting back to activity.

```
Activity.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener( {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Activity.fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        Activity.toolbar.setTitle("Activity");
        Activity.toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This is working fine with me:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

hope it helps somebody

Answer (score 1):

if you want to hide the navigationview icon from the toolbar on any Fragment use that code

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity)context;
    Toolbar toolbar = activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       toolbar.setTitle("Quiz");
       toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);

}
```