# black screen shows before open splash screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I searched a lot and I couldn't find any useful post. When I open my application (application use sherlock fragment ) shows black screen,application name with blue line in header and after 2 seconds appears splash screen. What should I do for passing this.. So when I press application button it show directly splash screen.

here is my style that I use

```
 <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/trans</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonMyTheme</item>
        <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButtonMyTheme</item>
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextMyTheme</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerMyTheme</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSpinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerMyTheme.DropDown</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItemMyTheme</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: check this http://thesoftwarerogue.blogspot.in/2010/12/skipping-entry-in-package-table-0.html

Comment: check this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525734/actionbar-lag-in-hiding-title if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove that blue line with header you need to add just below line in your custom theme and it will work for you.Set that theme as application Theme.

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

To display a resource for the background, and remove the title bar, you also need these nodes.

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```